# One who will survive

Tags: single-word-requests

I practice and teach survival skills such that I might survive in a sticky situation. These are things like wild water treatment, fire lighting, etc.

A survivalist is one who makes preparation to survive disaster by storing food, etc. It's largely used in the US to mean prepper.

A bushcrafter is one who practices bushcraft.

Since survivor is reserved for those who have survived, what do we, the ones who practice survival skills so that will survive, call ourselves?

UPDATE

This is for the UK where survivalist means prepper

Comment: Is 'bushcrafter' one of those made up words like 'detectorist'? Bushcraft being something you *have* not something you *do*, as with 'roadcraft' which means *knowledge and experience of roads*. For the question, you already mentioned 'survivalist' which seems to be in common use.

Comment: ... so someone who has roadcraft could be a *driver*, and someone with bushcraft could be a *hunter* or a *tracker*. Someone who practices survival skills could also be one of those, but without a greater purpose they might be called an Armageddonist, etc. No-one goes around saying "I am busy bushcrafting/surviving today" except maybe [Edina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_Fabulous).

Comment: @WeatherVane Those are generally apt. However, from the question, I understand there are two types of "survivors" (let's say): one collects Swiss army knives and goes camping or hiking for the adrenaline rush; another has an apocalyptic bunker that fits 12 in their backyard. I think the OP is looking to distance himself from *survivalist*, which implies the second meaning (because of its association with "prepper"), and lean towards the more casual "adrenaline junkie", "adventurer", or "survival enthusiast" version of "survivor".

Comment: I’ve heard them called ***survivalists***  and I wouldn’t call a*prepper* a survivalist.

Comment: Outdoorsman seems an option.

Comment: @WeatherVane In the UK, people are bushcrafters and go bushcrafting, but not surviving.

Comment: @TerryM Outdoorsman is very broad.

Comment: @Jim survivalist and preppers are the same in the UK

Comment: @niamulbengali Yes, and so the adventurer needs to be a something which practices survival skills so that if he gets into a survival situation, he can survive and become a survivor. Enthusiast is too casual and doesn't sound practical enough. Similarly, some people learn to shoot for fun, while some learn for defence. Survival [skills] enthusiasts learn for fun.

Comment: I don't think that "preppeer" and "survivalist" are the same creature: I see a prepper as the person with an underground store of food and ammunition, etc., and a survivalist as someone who can live for weeks in a hostile environment with little or nothing.

Comment: @stevemarvell to you mean people in the UK travel abroad to places that have bush so that they can "bushcraft". How exciting!

Comment: @stevemarvell - I’m disappointed to hear that... :-(

Comment: I think you can use "survivor". A [survivor](https://www.lexico.com/definition/survivor) is *1.2 A person who copes well with difficulties in their life.* It's not reserved for those who have survived (as you say in the question) but who *do* survive. I don't see why we need new words like "bushcrafting" for skills that have been around for a very long time.

Answer (score 3):

I would use ***survivalist***.

I don't think it's generally considered a synonym for "prepper."  There are [numerous](https://www.survivalsullivan.com/preppers-vs-survivalists/) [articles](https://www.traumasurvivalkits.com/blogs/news/survivalist-vs-prepper-whats-the-difference) online discussing the difference, with the overall theme being that *preppers* stockpile supplies, while *survivalists* learn survival skills.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivalism) includes both in the same article, though the article's [terminology section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivalism#Survivalist_terminology) calls "prepper" "A misconstrued synonym for survivalist... Incorrectly used interchangeably with *survivalist*."

Comment: I agree. Prepper has a rather negative connotation (at least in some circles), while survivalist is more neutral. The two also have different foci. A prepper is someone who starts by preparing for a future large-scale disaster, while a survivalist focuses on situational survival (downed plane, etc).

Comment: In the UK, a survivalist is a prepper. In Collins dictionary:

survivalist in British English
(səˈvaɪvəlɪst  )
NOUN
US
a. a person who believes in ensuring his or her personal survival of a catastrophic event by arming himself or herself and often by living in the wild
b. (as modifier)
survivalist weapons

It's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Even Google replaces one with the other on my searches.